# PHP coding problem to get multiple instances from an array based on quantity variable within

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm not sure if anyone can help me with a problem I have..

I have a parse function that includes the code:

```
foreach ($values as $element) {

$nodeName = $element["tag"];

switch ($element['type']) {

case 'open':

if ($nodeName == "SHOPPINGLIST") {
$this->publicationID = $element["attributes"]["PUBLICATIONID"]; 
}

if ($nodeName == "ENTRY") {

$entry = new ShoppingCartEntry();
$entry->quantity = $element["attributes"]["QUANTITY"];

}

if ($nodeName == "ITEM") {

$entry->productID = $element["attributes"]["PRODUCTID"];
$entry->price = $element["attributes"]["PRICE"];

array_push($this->entries, $entry);
}   

break;

case 'complete':

if ($nodeName == "NAME") {
$entry->name = $element["value"];
}

if ($nodeName == "DESCRIPTION") {
$entry->description = $element["value"];
}   

break;

}
}
```

As a result I have an array in the format of:

```
Array ( 
[0] => ShoppingCartEntry Object ( 
[quantity] => 3 
[productID] => 00001 
[price] => 4.99 
[name] => Full English 
[description] => Eggs, Beans, Sheesh Kebab Served with Toast )
```

At the minute I am printing the item entries using:

```
foreach ($entries as $entry) { 
}
```

However now I need an entry to be created for each quantity value there is of a product. So if the quantity of the product in the entry is 3, Then either an alteration needs to be made so that 3 entries are created or even if there is someway of editing the foreach loop, so that it loops for "$quantity" amount of times..

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
foreach ($entries as $entry)
{ 
    for ($i = 0; $i < $entry->quantity; $i++)
    {
        echo $entry->name . ': ' . ($i + 1) . ' of ' . $entry->quantity . '<br>';
    }
}
```